# $injector nomod Module 'angularFileUpload' is not available

Tags: angularjs, heroku, bower, mean.io, angular-file-upload

I'm currently using the mean.io stack for a personal project and everything runs smoothly locally. I tried to deploy to Heroku and I'm having problems with one module not instantiating properly! I found similar questions here on Stack Overflow, but none of the answers worked for me.

Here's my error:

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module mean due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angularFileUpload due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'angularFileUpload' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. (dist.min.js)

It seems like my module is not loading. But according to the logs, it installed properly:

> mean@0.3.3 postinstall /tmp/build_5d155aeb-14b5-4414-af19-986a68df3b19
>   node node_modules/bower/bin/bower install
>
> bower ng-file-upload-shim#* not-cached git://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload-shim-bower.git#*
>
> bower ng-file-upload-shim#*    resolve git://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload-shim-bower.git#*
>
> bower angular#*             not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#*
>   bower angular#*                resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#*
>   ...
>   bower ng-file-upload#*               not-cached git://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file->upload-bower.git#*
>
> bower ng-file-upload#*                  resolve git://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file->upload-bower.git#*
>
> ...
>
> bower ng-file-upload-shim#*             install ng-file-upload-shim#1.4.0
>
> bower ng-file-upload#*                  install ng-file-upload#1.4.0
>
> ...
>
> bower angular#1.2.19                    install angular#1.2.19
>
> ...
>
> Done, without errors.

Note: angularFileUpload by Danial Farid requires that the shim.js file is loaded before angular, which in turn gets loaded before angularFileUpload. Seems like angular got installed afterwards, would that be a problem?

Here's my module, where I declare dependency:

```
angular.module('mean.thingy', ['angularFileUpload','ngAnimate']).controller(...
```

and finally, my assets.json:

```
"js": {
            "public/build/js/dist.min.js": [
            "public/system/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            "public/system/lib/angular-file-upload-master/dist/angular-file-upload-shim.js",
            "public/system/lib/angular/angular.js",
            ...
            "public/system/lib/angular-file-upload-master/dist/angular-file-upload.js",
            "public/init.js",
            "public/*/*.js",
            "public/*/{controllers,routes,services}/*.js"
            ]
        }
```

I'd appreciate any help or hunches that you may have! Thanks!

Comment: is this resolved, any update will help

Comment: unfortunately, not yet :(

Comment: Not specific to this particular case but may help some (this post appears pretty high on google for this issue search): if your module is in a separate file, it also has to be included in the html: <script src="js/services.js"></script>

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error and it got fixed by adding the file path to karma.conf.js

Comment: Whats do you mean by Add the file path to Karma? Where exactly?

Comment: I got this error when running a test on file upload functionality. Karma is the test runner we used and it gave that error since it was not able to find the dependency while running the tests. It got solved when I manually added the js file `<some location>/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload.js` to the configuration file of test runner (which was in our case `karms.conf.js`).

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, I am using mean.js rather that mean.io so might be slightly different.

You were on the right track when you asked "Seems like angular got installed afterwards, would that be a problem?" I believe so.

To fix this, make sure that in your **production.js** config you put the scripts in the right order as well as in **all.js** e.g.

```
            'public/lib/ng-file-upload/FileAPI.min.js', 
            'public/lib/ng-file-upload/angular-file-upload-shim.min.js',
            'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
            'public/lib/ng-file-upload/angular-file-upload.min.js',
```

Comment: It fixed my problem.  I am also using mean.js.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change your upload dependency declaration to:

angular.module('mean.thingy', ['**ngFileUpload**','ngAnimate'])...

Comment: You should only change to this dependency if you are actually changing from using nervgh/angular-file-upload to danialfarid/ng-file-upload....

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because my local copies of angular-file-upload-shim.min.js and angular-file-upload.min.js were corrupted (I did not fetch them using bower).

Try downloading the raw .js files from the author's github page: https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload/tree/master/dist , click on the file, click on "Raw", then point your JS file to the local copies of these files.